# How to make prompt appear only after event listener finishes?

Tags: javascript, html

What I want to do is I want to make a prompt question if I want to continue(after temp result) or not if not then quit the page BUTTT whenever I put prompt or alert, they appear first instead of the value of the temperature.

```js
const result = document.querySelector(".result") /// button
const change = document.querySelector(".change") /// button
const screen = document.querySelector(".ctF") //h1
const tscreen = document.querySelector(".screen") ///h1
const dta = [{
  index: 1,
  message: "Celcius to Fahrenheit"
}, {
  index: 2,
  message: "Fahrenheit to Celcius"
}]
let num = 0
let iV = 1

change.addEventListener("click", () => {
  num++
  if (num > dta.length - 1) {
    num = 0
  }
  t(num)
})

function t(ss) {
  let item = dta[ss]
  let message = item.message
  let index = item.index
  iV = index
  tscreen.innerHTML = message
  screen.innerHTML = "Temperature"
}

result.addEventListener("click", changeTemp)

function changeTemp() {
  const value = document.querySelector(".input").value ///input
  let numbaW = 1
  let numbaT = 2
  if (numbaW == iV) {
    let cetFa = value * (1.8) + 32
    screen.innerHTML = Math.round(cetFa) + "°F"
    window.addEventListener("message")
  } else if (numbaT == iV) {
    let fatCe = ((value - 32) * 5) / 9
    screen.innerHTML = Math.round(fatCe) + "°C"
  }
}
```

Comment: _"whenever I put prompt or alert"_... neither of which appear anywhere in your question code 

Comment: I put it inside changeTemp(if else) function and it just did not work. When I put it along with changeTemp, it doesn't appear every time I click result. So I am confused what to do.

Answer (score 0):

`prompt` and `alert` are both halting the JavaScript event loop.
This means as long as the user does not click on "ok" no DOM modifications will be processed.
The solution will be to `prompt` the user after a timeout.

Ususally

```js
setTimeout(() => {
  let value = prompt("What's the value?");
  alert(`Value: ${value}`);
});
```

should do the trick for you.

Comment: I want to make it appear right after result event listener everytime instead before. When I put this inside changeTemp, it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: You have to post your (not working) current approach, else I can't really help you since I don't know what you attempted.

Comment: It's not even worth posting that here. Basically I put prompt or setTimeout inside and outside if else statements and one along with the changeTemp function near the event listener but that's not how I am supposed to do . I have to make prompt appear everytime new temperature appears after clicking the result button.